# Accessing list of objects inside a dictionary

Tags: python, django

How would i print out dictionary values that are a list of objects. More specifically attributes from the objects

Output from a print of the dictionary

```
    for keys,values in Dict.items():
        print(keys)
        print(values)

Five
[<VocabContent: Seven - 7>, <VocabContent: Ten - 10>, <VocabContent: Six - 6>, <VocabContent: Eight - 8>, <VocabContent: Five - 5>]
Eight
[<VocabContent: Ten - 10>, <VocabContent: Eight - 8>, <VocabContent: Six - 6>, <VocabContent: Five - 5>, <VocabContent: Seven - 7>]
```

These objects have spanish and audio attributes. I'm trying to print the objects spanish attribute with

```
for keys,values in Dict.items():
    print values.spanish
```

But it does not work. My webpage just returns a server error 500

How can i access the object attributes from the dictionary

Thanks

Comment: You need to loop over the values.

Comment: Thanks Melo. Soon as you msged that i realised what I missed. Klemens answered confirmed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to loop over the values of the list

```
for keys,values in Dict.items():
    for value in values:
        print(value.spanish)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Looks so obvious now...
Now trying to use it in templates on django. But no luck.

I'm guessing the .items() is not accepted in templates tags..
What would be the equivelant?

Thanks

Comment: You could try to loop over the keys and access the dictionary with the key instead.

Comment: I found the answer to my second question... just delete () when using in templates for django...

Just a side question. Can anybody tell me what type of list is used when returning a query set? is it a dictonary or list of objects?

Comment: @Leo505 QuerySet is a class of its own, if that is what you are asking.
Essentialy, it behaves like a list when you try to iterate over it, but otherwise it is not the same. Source code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L155